# Fabric.js: src attribute missing on grouping subclassed object

Tags: fabricjs

I tried to use subclassing as shown in the example at http://fabricjs.com/polaroid.

The PolaroidPhoto subclass just adds a border on the image as shown on the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gusy54rr/6/

```
   canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    HOVER_CURSOR: 'pointer'
  });

  var PolaroidPhoto = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
    H_PADDING: 20,
    V_PADDING: 20,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    initialize: function(src, options) {
      this.callSuper('initialize', options);
      this.image = new Image();
      this.image.src = src;
    console.log("In initialize, src is:" + src);
      this.image.onload = (function() {
        this.width = this.image.width;
        this.height = this.image.height;
        this.loaded = true;
        this.setCoords();
        this.fire('image:loaded');
      }).bind(this);
    },
    _render: function(ctx) {
      if (this.loaded) {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        ctx.fillRect(
          -(this.width / 2) - this.H_PADDING,
          -(this.height / 2) - this.H_PADDING,
          this.width + this.H_PADDING * 2,
          this.height + this.V_PADDING * 2);
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
      }
    }
  });
  var photo = new PolaroidPhoto('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqmQ9.png', { });

 photo.on('image:loaded', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

 photo.set('scaleX', 1);
 photo.set('scaleY', 1);
 photo.set('top', 180);
 photo.set('left', 150);
    console.log("photo,src is :" + photo.get('src'));

  // forcing src value (but ineffective)
 photo.set('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqmQ9.png');

   canvas.add(photo);


canvas.add(
   rect= new fabric.Rect({ top: 50, left: 100, width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#f55' }),
 circle =   new fabric.Circle({ top: 140, left: 230, radius: 75, fill: 'green' }),
   triangle = new fabric.Triangle({ top: 300, left: 210, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'blue' })
);

$("#group").on('click', function() {
    var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();

    activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);  
            });
            canvas.add(newgroup);

    });
});

$("#ungroup").click(function(){
   var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(activeObject.type=="group"){
            var items = activeObject._objects;
            alert(items);
            activeObject._restoreObjectsState();
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                canvas.add(items[i]);
            items[i].dirty = true;
                canvas.item(canvas.size()-1).hasControls = true;
            }
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

It works fine until I want to stringify or make some grouping with a subclassed object.

In the fiddle, I completed the Fabric demo's example by adding a few basis objects (a rectangle, a circle and a triangle). 
If I select the subclassed image and any other object and then click on the group button:
The image disappears.

The scr property of the photo is not set (as shown by the alert on "ungroup" for the former group).

A stringification of the canvas also shows that "src" is missing.

Even if I force (see the fiddle) a src value using "photo.set('src',...)"  :
    - the grouping still makes the picture to disappear.
    - The stringification still lacks the "src" attribute. (I tried to extend toObjects to no avail)

How to get grouping and stringification to work with subclassed objects?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/gusy54rr/7/), this in version `2.0.0-beta7`

Comment: Thanks a lot Durga. Indeed, grouping is fine with your nice conversion to version 2.0.0-beta7 .
But, loadFromJSON still does not make it.
Anyway, I must still find a way to make both grouping and loadFromJSON to work with fabric 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a new jsfiddle showing correct grouping and JSON load with a sub-classed (PolaroidPhoto) image. Fabric version is 1.7.19
https://jsfiddle.net/rpzk7wL6/2/

I put some comments in the code to show my modifications.
The main problem in the former script was the absence of fromObjects() method.
I also added a handler listening to "image:loaded" to the sub-class instance created
 by fromObjects, in order to render it after loading .

```
      fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

   canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    HOVER_CURSOR: 'pointer'
  });

 fabric.Polaroidphoto = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
type: 'polaroidphoto',
    H_PADDING: 20,
    V_PADDING: 20,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    initialize: function(src, options) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = src;
        this.callSuper('initialize',src, options);
        console.log("initialize, src:" + src);
        this.image.onload = (function() {
            this.width = this.image.width;
        console.log("initialize, scaleX:" + this.image.scaleX);
            this.height = this.image.height;
        this.src= this.image.src;
        console.log("initialize image.onload, src:" + src);
            this.loaded = true;
            this.setCoords(); 
            this.fire('image:loaded');
            }).bind(this);
        },
    _render: function(ctx) {
    if (this.loaded) {
        console.log("_render:is_loaded");
            ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
            ctx.fillRect(
                -(this.width / 2) - this.H_PADDING,
                 -(this.height / 2) - this.H_PADDING,
                this.width + this.H_PADDING * 2,
                this.height + this.V_PADDING * 2);
                ctx.drawImage(this.image, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
        } else {
        console.log("_render:is_NOT__loaded");
        }
    }
  });

// Added fromObject function for sub-class 
fabric.Polaroidphoto.async = true;
fabric.Polaroidphoto.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
console.log("fabric.Polaroidphoto.fromObject object.src) :" + object.src);
            var instance = new fabric.Polaroidphoto(object.src, object);
            callback && callback(instance);
    // added handler to render instance 
        instance.on('image:loaded', when_loaded );
          };

 var photo = new fabric.Polaroidphoto('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqmQ9.png', { });
 photo.on('image:loaded', when_loaded );
 photo.set('scaleX', 1);
 photo.set('scaleY', 1);
 photo.set('top', 180);
 photo.set('left', 150);
 canvas.add(photo);


canvas.add(
   rect= new fabric.Rect({ top: 50, left: 100, width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#f55' }),
 circle =   new fabric.Circle({ top: 140, left: 230, radius: 75, fill: 'green' }),
   triangle = new fabric.Triangle({ top: 300, left: 210, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'blue' })
);

// required at load to render sub-classed image in group
function when_loaded() {
    console.log("when_loaded");
    dirty(); // to set dirty : true 
    canvas.renderAll();
}

// required at load to display sub-classed image in group, 
// set dirty:true for groups 

function dirty() {
    $.each(canvas._objects, function( index, obj ) {
        if( typeof obj.type !== 'undefined' && obj.type == 'group') {
            obj.dirty= true;
        }
    });
}

$("#group").on('click', function() {
    var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();

    activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);  
            });
             canvas.add(newgroup);
        newgroup.dirty = true; 
    });
});

$("#ungroup").click(function(){
   var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(activeObject.type=="group"){
            var items = activeObject._objects;
            alert(items);
            activeObject._restoreObjectsState();
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                canvas.add(items[i]);
            items[i].dirty = true;
            canvas.item(canvas.size()-1).hasControls = true;
            }
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Thanks